# change class with javascript and store with cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, addclass

I am using this javascript where I can change a class onClick (other class).

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".changefontA").click(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("a").addClass("b");
    $(this).hide();
    $(".changefontB").fadeIn();
});
$(".changefontB").click(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("b").addClass("a");
    $(this).hide();
    $(".changefontA").fadeIn();
});
});
```

Because it's a huge change in the font I want to store it in a cookie so when the visitor goes to another page, the website will remember the change and don't switch back to the original font. I'm completely new to cookies so I hope someone can help me or give me a head start.

Comment: you can look at a plugin like [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which will help you set/get cookie values... based on browser's you want to support you can think about [webstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) also

Comment: Without cookies, you could store it in database but I think cookie is a good solution. 
To do so, take a look here : http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin, you could do something like

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".changefontA").on('click.myfont', function () {
        $("body").removeClass("a").addClass("b");
        $(this).hide();
        $(".changefontB").fadeIn();
        $.cookie('my-font', 'changefontA', {
            path: '/'
        });
    });
    $(".changefontB").on('click.myfont', function () {
        $("body").removeClass("b").addClass("a");
        $(this).hide();
        $(".changefontA").fadeIn();
        $.cookie('my-font', 'changefontB', {
            path: '/'
        });
    });

    //set the class based on the already set cookie
    var font = $.cookie('my-font');
    if (font) {
        $('.' + font).trigger('click.myfont');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pjv7r8ra/)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your target environment etc, I'd consider using HTML5 web storage - sessionStorage (exists just for the existing session), or localStorage (permanently stored or until storage is cleared).

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".changefontA").click(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("a").addClass("b");
    $(this).hide();
    $(".changefontB").fadeIn();
    sessionStorage['fontClass'] = "b";
});
$(".changefontB").click(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("b").addClass("a");
    $(this).hide();
    $(".changefontA").fadeIn();
    sessionStorage['fontClass'] = "a";
});
});
```

On each page, you can check if you have a previous setting stored and set the class accordingly

```
 if ('fontClass' in sessionStorage) {
   // remove any default class setting here first
   $("body").addClass(sessionStorage['fontClass']);
 }
```

Comment: What are the pro's and con's using this instead of cookies? :)

Comment: cookies are stored in http headers, which might be switched off by the user, and are frankly messy to code.  session/local storage offer much larger space, are supported natively by browsers but not IE7 or earlier.  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: as another point of principle, cookies are designed to carry information between the client/browser and the webserver.  In this case the use of sessionStorage makes much more sense as its client-only - don't bother your webserver with the overhead of carrying font settings around, unless you are storing them away in a server-side client profile.  regards.